# Make a list with no formatting in ASP and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make the simplest of query's using C# and listing them in ASP.NET. I am slightly confused about this. I am familiar with C# but not sure how i would list them in ASP.NET as i have just started using this language.

Right i have a table called Recipes. I am trying to retrieve the Recipe_ID and Name and list them. one below the other. No formatting.

```
1 item1
2 item2
3 item3
etc...
```

Any help will be great. I apologies for this stupid question. I just may not be researching the right things.

***C#***

```
   private void loadRecipe()
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            //Fetching top recipe     
            string query = ("SELECT Recipe_ID, Recipe_Name FROM Recipe");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);


           [[[what goes here]]]


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {



        }

        con.Close();
    }
```

***ASP.NET***

```
[[[What do i need for this]]]
```

Comment: This tutorial shows a simple way to use the GridView: http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/util/srcview.aspx?path=~/aspnet/samples/data/GridViewSimple.src.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the fold. Everyone starts somewhere. There are much, much better ways of doing this - this is essentially a hack, loading everything into a string and populating a label. But, it will show you how to access the data. Look at [ASP GridView](https://quickstarts.asp.net/quickstartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/gridview.aspx).

**C#**

```
private void loadRecipe()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
    try
    {
        //Fetching top recipe     
        string query = ("SELECT * Recipe_ID, Recipe_Name FROM Recipe");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        String body;
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        if(dr.HasRows){
            while(dr.Read()){
                body += count++ + " " + dr["Body"].ToString() + "<br />";  
          }
        }
        myLabel.Text = body;
    }
    catch (Exception){}
    conn.Close();
}
```

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="myLabel" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

First rewritre LoadRecipe method:

```
    private DataTable LoadRecipe()
    {
       DataTable recipe = new DataTable();
       var connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True"

        using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString){
         con.Open();
          try       
            {
              //Fetching top recipe     
                var query = ("SELECT Recipe_ID, Recipe_Name FROM Recipe");
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                recipe.Load(dr);
    }
      catch (Exception ex)
           {
             throw; //(or logg)
           }
      finally // ensure that connection would be closed at any case
           {            
              con.Close();
           }
      }
        return recipe;
        }
```

**In your controller** *(if you using ASP MVC)*

```
public ActionResult Index()
  {
    var recepy = LoadRecipe();
    return View(recepy); //passing the DataTable to the View
  }
```

and in you **View**

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <%foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns) { %>
                <th><%=col.Caption %></th>
            <%} %>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% foreach(System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows) { %>
        <tr>
            <% foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray) {%>
            <td><%=cell.ToString() %></td>
            <%} %>
        </tr>
    <%} %>         
    </tbody>
</table>
```

That would pass DataTable to the View and represent them as a Table